# How to remove the pager for a CListView?

Tags: yii

Hi here i am using CListView and i want to remove the pager header which is like this

[first] [previous]  1  2  3  4  [next] [last]

i want to remove all this the code here i am using is

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
'itemView'=>'_view',
'enablePagination' => false ));
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the [`template`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CListView#template-detail) property to `"{summary}\n{sorter}\n{items}"`, which differs from the default of `"{summary}\n{sorter}\n{items}\n{pager}"` in that it does not display the pager at all.

Answer (score 0):

PostController.php:

```
$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Post',
                    array(
                    'criteria'=>$criteria,
                    'pagination'=>array(
                                    'pageSize'=>1,
                            ),
                    )
            );
```

and this is view:

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'itemView'=>'_view',
    'enableSorting'=>true,
    'template'=>"{items}\n{pager}", //this remove: Displaying #... of ... result
    'cssFile'=> Yii::app()->theme->baseUrl.'/style.css',
)); ?>
```